# How should I handle parent and child users in my Postgres db design?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, database-design, roles

I'm building a platform targeted to kids with an optional parent sign up. Regular users can access the full platform experience while parent users can only access a parent dashboard to create their child's account, manage it, and see activity from their child.

Parent accounts will never become users. If they want to be a regular user they must make a separate user account.

Two ways I can create this:

1. A single `users` table with an `account_type` column. This is what I currently have.
2. Separate tables, `users` and `parents`, as well as an `accounts` table that has a one-to-one mapping to either (for things like email, password hash, etc.).

#2 seems like the better longterm solution. The pros are that I can evolve the two separately, and the cons are that basic user queries become slightly more complicated.

Any thoughts or recommendations on these two approaches?

Comment: This will be strictly opinion based. But as for mine it #2. I agree with your pro for it, disagree that your basic user queries become slightly more complicated. Both schema require you retrieving the same data. While schema #2 requires simple inner join; schema #1 is likely to involve a left outer self join with attribute value verification.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a role based user maangement.

you will have `user`, `role` models.

In `user` model you will have a column `roleid` having a object-type-relationship[one-to-one] with `role` model.

Now, in your user model you will give the permission to parent user (role account) to create a child user (role account).

ask me if you need further explanation.